# making a picture of a neural network in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I'm new to Machine Learning and I have just gone through a tutorial explaining how to create a neural network in TensorFlow. I was wondering if it is possible to visualize the neural network I created. The output should be a picture like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#/media/File:Colored_neural_network.svg)

Thanks.

MRE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(ann, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, 
                          show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB',
                          expand_nested=False, dpi=96
                          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
        model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_layer_names=True,
        rankdir='TB', expand_nested=False, dpi=96
    )
```

This will generate an image like:

[image]

Example: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: That doesn't seem to work perfectly. I'm getting a png file with a single box saying 'sequential_1'  I'm using tf 2.0 and I have a network with four layers (including input / output)

Comment: If you update the question with some code, I can have a look. Include the part where you define the model etc.

Comment: added MRE code to the post

Comment: Was able to get this to work following the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227174/why-plot-model-in-keras-does-not-plot-the-model-correctly  I needed to specify the shape of the input layer using ```ann.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(12,)))```